# AJAX url routing issue in IIS with virtual directory

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, url-routing

I got a `.NET MVC3` project which was just deployed to an actual server inside a virtual directory. Let's call it `VirtDir`. My JavaScript files all had URLs for AJAX defined like this:

```
"/Home/Save/"
```

which was working fine locally.

On the actual server, that first "/" kills the virtual directory, so I get

`"/Home/Save/"` instead of `"/VirtDir/Home/Save/"` which obviously fails.

If I remove the first "/", then things break locally, resulting in defined URL being appended to the URL of the current page: If you're on `"/Home/Index"` page, the AJAX URL would point to

`"/Home/Index/Home/Save"`.

My JavaScript is in separate *.js files, so I can't really write `@Url.Content` to them.

Anyone knows of a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can add some code to your layout file or master page that writes out the root directory to a JS variable before including the JS file. Then you can use that variable to build the path in your JS file.

In Razor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rootDir = "@Url.Content("~/")";
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MyScript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then you can just build your url in your file like this:

```
var myurl = rootDir + "Home/Save/";
```

Comment: Thanks.  I actually ended up doing something similar to this.

Comment: hello @Dimskiy, can you comment what you ended up doing?